# How to use flex with java to develope an application

Tags: java, flex4

I just passed out from Bcs.
I dont know anything in flex,but i wish to work with it as challange
And more important and worst thing is i dont know how i can work with java and flex

Comment: Have you tried [googles search engine](http://www.google.com/search?q=Java+Flex) already?

Answer (score 0):

For integrating flex with java ( for example tomcat or jetty servers ) you'd need blazeDS ( google will help you find it ), which is open sourced by adobe.

Comment: Hey thnx luno surely i will check this now